# How to trigger a method periodically?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public Data GetData()
{
    ...
    updateCache();
}

public void timer()
{
    //I would like to call GetData() every minute
}
```

I would like to trigger `GetData()` every minute and update a cache.

What is the best way to do this in C#?

Comment: you can go ahead with timer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) is the simplest and easiest way.

Comment: Or use a background thread for it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830346/recurring-background-task

Comment: There are at least a million ways of solving this, some are better for some scenarios - I assumed OP wanted to have the simplest and shortest one, and in my opinion that is the Timer. But sure enough using a thread is easy as well.