# How can I get current location instantly (within 2-3 seconds) in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin

I want to get current location within 2-3 seconds. Tell me the right way to do it. I am thinking to use both **GPS** and **Mobile Network**. 
Two different scenarios I have tried described below

1. I was working only with **GPS** while sitting in a room, which was taking more than 15 seconds and on the other hand, **GPS** needs "Line of sight".
2. I was working with **GPS** + Wifi (not connected with any network)
   while sitting in a room, which was taking more than 8 seconds.

So, it was taking way more time as I was expecting.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a task that gets the location every 2-3 seconds?

Code to get location https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8c19e8/xamarin-android-working-with-gps-and-locations/

but I personally prefer using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Geolocator/

And check this for creating a recurring task [Recurring Background Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830346/recurring-background-task)