# Any reason why Winforms Timer does not tick?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

I have multiple timers running on my windows app. Each timer_tick runs a code. Right now I am working on two processes.

```
private async void tmrProcessDelay_Tick
private async void tmrAutopay_Tick
```

Just recently added the `tmrAutopay` as an added process so that instead of sequential process, I made them work at the same time. The problem I am having is that I am not able to restart the process of the Autopay.

Timers are declared at the top as an instance when form loads.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmrProcessDelay = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
private System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmrAutopay = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

tmrAutopay.Interval = 2000;
tmrAutopay.Enabled = false;
tmrAutopay.Tick += new EventHandler(tmrAutopay_Tick);

private async void tmrAutopay_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        messagebox("tick"); // correcting this one
        txtNotes.AppendText("tick"); 
        tmrAutopay.Enabled = false;
        // do some code
        tmrAutopay.Enabled = true;
    }
```

**EDIT:** as per *Michael Randall* suggestion, I tried adding break point at the top. I got the issue. Just on the logic. I just thought that it doesn't start again because "tick" only appends once, so I assumed it only ran once. When I went adding the break point, it ticked again, but for some reason, it did not `appendText`, reason I did assume things. Going back to the problem, due to the existing logic, after

1. called tick one - appendtext
2. enabled = true - ticked but did not append
3. due to logic, it did not go to enabled = true again

The timer tick only runs after I enabled it the first time, then when its ticks, I set it to false to do some code then start it again after finishing.

I have yet to try [this system timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412145/timer-wont-tick) solution, and also saw some post that timers won't run on background process, since I can run it one time, it means it can.. But I just wanna ask before I change timers if there are any reasons why I am having this issue?

Comment: You ask a lot of C# questions for a VB enthusiast :) Are you saying that after you enable it for the first time, it ticks a single time and then never again?

Comment: @John Yes, that's correct. For example I do `tmrAutopay.Enabled = true` on form load. Yes it ticks, I tried adding a breakpoint if it really reaches the enable = true, which it does, but it doesn't go to the tick method, so I assume timer did not start? I started in Visual Basic, hence the name :)

Comment: So you never see the "tick" messagebox?

Comment: There is a lot of missing information here, what sort of timer is it, when do you enable it (what code in your question), you mention `adding a breakpoint if it really reaches the enable = true` in comments, yet did you try breakpoint `messagebox("tick");`

Comment: Have you got a timer instance in your class, or you just create it in some method and start timing? If you just create it in a method - timer could be removed by GC

Comment: private async void tmrAutopay_Tick - why are you using async?

Comment: Can you put more complete code thanks, there are too many questions here

Comment: Hi guys. I edited my question, thank you so much for your help. its just a logic problem. or maybe the AppendText has some bug..

Comment: Most likely you have something running in one or both of the `// do some code` portions of your Timers that is preventing the Timer Tick events from being processed.  The Tick() event runs in the main UI thread, so if you have a tight loop running in your "work" it'll prevent the other Timers Tick() event from being processed until that loop is exited.  It's pretty hard to troubleshoot your problem without seeing all the code.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to make like background process then you can do window service application and implement more than one timer in that code. I had good working experience with this type of application and I am confident that it will work without any issue with multiple timers. the only thing you need to be careful in code is that in case if some code takes longer than expected and more than timer interval then it will start another thread which could end up as deadlock for that timer or crash the application. Each timer works independently and creates a new thread each time when it ticks.